# Confluent Load Connector invalid JSON - parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am playing around with Kafka on my Mac and keep getting the same error. Hoping for a little guidance as I've had no luck with Google currently.

For reference I'm following this article https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/

I created a JSON connector file to connect my database to Kafka and I get the following response

```
$ bin/confluent load jdbc_source_sql -d kafka-connect-jdbc-source.json

This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7
```

Here is what my JSON looks like (cleaned)

```
{
"name": "jdbc_source_sql",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://t.t.t.com;database=t;username=t;password=t;",
    "table.whitelist": "KafkaTesting",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name": "timestamp",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "topic.prefix": "sql-"
    }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I might suggest trying a raw `curl` command instead rather than `confluent load` to debug the issue further, otherwise, the JSON you posted looks okay

Comment: +1 for trying `curl`, e.g. `curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8083/connectors/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @kafka-connect-jdbc-source.json`